# flutter run pub run build_runner build failed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, json-serializable, json-annotation

[used json annotation and serializable ][1]

[Not understanding the error][2]

Comment: Please don't send screenshots of your code and send them im your question by copy paste it in a code balise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't name the instance of the object with the same name as the object.
This will do the trick:

```
addproductmodel _addproductmodel = addproductmodel(product_name: _productname.text);
```

You class's names also should start with uppercase letter for clarity. I recommand you to read [this.](https://devopedia.org/naming-conventions)